# How to make the report in SSRS in an orderly manner

Tags: reporting-services

I have a report with days Monday Schedule 1, Monday Schedule 2, Tuesday Schedule 1, Tuesday Schedule 2, Wednesday schedule 1, Wednesday schedule 2, Thursday schedule 1, Thursday schedule 2, Friday schedule 1, Friday schedule 2. When I run the report the days and schedules are not in order. How can I put them in order in SSRS?

[Attached is my MSSQL Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ixaUz.png)

[This is what I aimed to acheive.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iXplL.png)

Comment: Please share more details, How report looks like and what output you are expecting

Comment: Dear Naveen,

Below is a more detail of my MSSQL table.

Columns: SchoolYear
                Term
                GradeLvl
                SubjectID
                TestDay
                TestTime
                TestCoverage.

Everyday (Monday for example) there are 2 schedules for the exam, i.e. Monday, 8-9 Math 
      Monday 9-10 Science.

Comment: You need to order by the test date (as per report screenshot) but your table doesn't have a test date in it. To put it another way: when you have two 'Monday' records, does it matter which Monday record comes first?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid, Should be the first schedule of every day should comes first. Example, Monday 8am-9am should comes first before Monday 9am-10am. You gave me an idea of ordering it by test date. I will change my table according to your suggestion.

Comment: Yes as I said you need to order it by test date which will naturally order it by weekday but first you need to put that in your table

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid, your suggestion worked. What I did is that instead of making a test date and sort it in order, I made another column "Test Sequence" and sort this in order. But I got another problem, whenever I will make an update to any columns in my table, the whole row in my SSRS report will vanish. Any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, I think the easiest way to go about this would be to add a derived column in your data called DAY.

Line up the respective days in this fashion:

```
         DAY   | MyDataColumn

        Monday | Monday S1

        Monday | Monday S2 

        Tuesday| Tuesday S1

        Tuesday| Tuesday S2
        etc....
```

Then, you can group by the new derived column 'DAY' in your report

Comment: Could you please make it clearer. I am new in SSRS. My table in MSSQL looks like this:

Columns: SchoolYear
                Term
                GradeLvl
                SubjectID
                TestDay
                TestTime
                TestCoverage.

Everyday (Monday for example) there are 2 schedules for the exam, i.e. Monday, 8-9 Math 
      Monday 9-10 Science.

Comment: @HoldOn can you screenshot your dataset? The above does not depict what you are trying to explain

Comment: I already added a screenshot of my database. It's located below to the question. I added also what I aimed to achieve.